# Assign a value to column of custom list

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list

I have used custom list having number of columns to display count.I have applied REST approach to get count.Now I am trying to display that count in a column.I used fd.field().value('Default title') in a script editor.(both api code and fd.field().value('Default title') code are in a same script editor).While using 'fd',I am getting error as fd is undefined.So is there any approach to display rest api output into a column?

Code:

```
    getListItemsForView(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,<List name>,<View 
    Name>)
.done(function(data)
{
     var items = data.d.results;
     fd.field(<column_name>).value(data.d.results.length);
     for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
         console.log(items[i].Title);
     }    
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: please post your code for reference, are you using js link to display count...?

Comment: please refer the code

Comment: what is fd object defined or declared and what is its type ?

Comment: fd is forms designer manager global variable. I got this solution(to use fd) from https://spform.com/javascript-framework/getting-setting-sharepoint-form-field-values.
I added same code in sharepoint  designer too but it is not working

Comment: are you trying to display count in list forms or list view ?

Comment: I am trying to assign in list view

Comment: I thin link you mentioned, form designer is not for list view it is to customize forms...

Comment: You need to use CSR or js link to customize list view..

Comment: Are you adding the list items count in another list or same list?

Comment: @GaneshSanap I am adding it in another list.

Comment: Then in `.done` function, you need to make another REST call to add/update the list item in another list. [Reference](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-on-a-sharepoint-list-using-rest-api/) for Add/Update item in SharePoint list using REST.

Comment: Ok..I will try..Is there any other approach other than REST call?

Comment: @GaneshSanap Thak you..It resolved my problem.

Comment: In your case either you need to use REST/JSOM. Please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding the list items count in another list then in `.done` function, you need to make another REST call to add/update the list item in another list.

If You want to create new record in another list then you can use something like this in `.done` function:

```
$.ajax({  
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Your List Name')/items",  
    type: "POST",  
    headers: {  
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"  
    },  
    data: "{__metadata:{'type':'SP.Data.YourlistnameListItem'}, ItemCount:" Your list item count "}",  
    /*Assuming you have added ItemCount column to add item count and you can add more columns by splitting with ,*/  
    success: function(data) {  
        console.log(data.d.results);  
    },  
    error: function(error) {  
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));  
    }  
});
```

Reference for Add/Update item in SharePoint list using REST:

[CRUD Operations On A SharePoint List Using REST API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-on-a-sharepoint-list-using-rest-api/).

Answer (score 0):

To customize list view you have to use JS link.....

I would suggest you to go through this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-make-sharepoint-field-data-as-hyper-link-using-js-link/)  to understand concept and then modify it for your purpose.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
(function () {  
    // Create an object that have the context information about the fields that we want to change the rendering of.   
    var nameFiledContext = {};  
    nameFiledContext.Templates = {};  
    nameFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {  
        // Apply the new rendering for these fields on List View  
        "<ColumnName>": { "View": nameFiledTemplate }  
    };  
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(nameFiledContext);  
})();  

// This function provides the rendering logic for the list view  
function nameFiledTemplate(ctx) {  

getListItemsForView(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,<List name>,<View 
    Name>)
.done(function(data)
{
     var items = data.d.results;
     return data.d.results.length;    
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});

}  
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks...I will try it

Comment: I tried this approach but it is not executing nameFiledTemplate function

Comment: Did you replace column name with actual internal name of column

Comment: yes,I replaced it

Comment: I am applying getListItemsForView function to get view count from a different list say list 1 and after getting count I am trying to assign it in list 2's column i.e.nameFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {  
        // Apply the new rendering for these fields on List View  
        "<ColumnName>": { "View": nameFiledTemplate }  
    };  here,in place of column name I am passing list2's column name.
So is it causing an issue?

Comment: are you browsing list2 view or list 1 view'?

Comment: I am browisng list2 view.The problem got solved by another solution.Thanks for your help

Comment: What was the solution... post it for others reference...please upvote if my answer was helpful

Comment: I used another REST call in .done function to add/update the list item in another list as I am adding the list items count in another list.